# After running a max flow algorithm, find in a flow network all edges that are in some min-cut

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-flow

Let G=(V,A,s,t,U) be a flow network. Suppose we have obtained a max flow. Is there a fast algorithm to find all edges that are in some min-cut?

I know that if `x` is a max flow, then we can find in the residual network `G(x)` the set `S` of vertices reachable from the source `s`, and `T` the set of vertices from which we can reach `t`. And consequently, `S` and its complement is a min-cut. Moreover, `T` and its complement also form a min-cut.

If, unfortunately, it happens that `T` is not the complement of `S`, then the min-cut is not unique. And I am wondering whether there is a good way to determine whether the edges whose ends lie in neither `S` nor `T` belong to a min-cut or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each arc `u-->v` belongs to some `s--t` min cut if and only if

1. there is no residual path from `u` to `t`,
2. there is no residual path from `s` to `v`, and
3. there is no residual path from `u` to `v`.

To prove the if direction, consider the cut consisting of vertices reachable from `s` or `u` by a residual path, which is an `s--t` cut by (1), has zero residual capacity and hence is an `s--t` min cut by construction, and contains `u-->v` by (2) and (3).

To prove the only if direction, we can use an `s--t` min cut that contains `u-->v` to show that, for every path from `u` to `t`, from `s` to `v`, or from `u` to `v`, some arc in the path is non-residual.

This gets you to `O(n m)` time fairly easily. Maybe that's good enough -- if it isn't, there is a literature on answering offline reachability queries that might be useful.

Comment: Does 3 imply 1 and 2?

Comment: @TomBennett It doesn't.

Comment: Here is what I'm thinking. There is an edge u->v in G but no edge in Gf implies there's an edge v->u in Gf. Because there is positive flow on  edge u->v, there is a reverse path u->s in Gf. So if 2 is not true, there's a path s->v in Gf, then there is a path from u to v in Gf, which is u->s->v. Similar for 3 => 1.

Comment: @TomBennett you have to be careful about what counts as a valid max flow---the standard definition allows flow to be pushed round a disconnected cycle.

Comment: I still think 3 implies 1 and 2. If 3 is true, then the edge u->v cannot be on a disconnected cycle. Then what I said before applies.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible (although less efficient answer than stated by @David Eisenstat) is by repeated calls to an algorithm (e.g., Ford–Fulkerson) for computing the max-flow/min-cut:

The idea behind this algorithm is to go (i) through every edge (`e` in `E`, `|E|=m`), (ii) reduce the capacity of `e` by exactly `1`, (iii) restart the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, and (iv) if the max-flow changes we know `e` has to be in some min-cut.

Argument for correctness: Indeed, this works as every min-cut (with capacity `C`) has some capacity that corresponds exactly to the max-flow and the sum of the capacities of the outgoing edges. If we now reduce this capacity, we get a reduced maximum flow (which is noticeable by the algorithm).
We are further not "overcounting edges", as every other cut has capacity `C'` (and `C'>=C+1` as we assume to be in an integer domain). Therefore reducing its capacity by `1` won't lead to a change in the overall max-flow/min-cut capacity.

Assuming we have `n` vertices (`|V|=n`), and `m` edges (`|E|=m`), we can compute a max flow in `O(m*n)`, and we can get all our edges which have an effect on the max-flow/min-cut in `O(m^2*n)`.

```
Algorithm-Pseudo-Code:
  G <- Flow-Network
  v <- maxFlowAlgorithm(G)
  P <- EmptySet
  for e in E:
    G' <- copy(G)
    G' <- reduceCapacityByOne(G',e)
    v' <- maxFlowAlgorithm(G')
    if v' < v:
      P <- P UNION {e}
  return P
```